# how to display point circle in a chart with chart.js, when not hovering directly on the line?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have a chart using chart.js, it's a simple line, and if I hover over the line everything is correct, a circle shows on the point and the tool tip appears.

Now I also wanted that when the user hovers on the X-axis, it would select the circle and show the tooltip for the value at that X-axis point.

So I added this:

```
tooltips: {
                    intersect: false,
                    mode: "index"
}
```

and it works correctly, now if I hover on the X-axis I'll get the tooltip on my line, but one thing that doesn't work is, I dont get the "circle" on my line, only the tooltip!

I get the circle only if I hover directly on the line, here 2 images so you can see the difference:

[image]

in the above image I'm hovering directly on the line, and it shows the Circle and the tooltip

[image]

in this image instead I'm hovering on the X-axis and as you can see, it will display only the tooltip on my line, but not the circle!

How can I display the circle even when not hovering directly?

thank you

EDIT: added more code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ctx = this.myChartRef.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        this.canvas = new Chart(this.ctx, {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Grade",
                        data: [],
                        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                        fill: false,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        showLine: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        radius: 0,
                        hitRadius: 10,
                        hoverRadius: 8
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    displayColors: false,
                    intersect: false,
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: "index",
                    callbacks: {
                        afterBody: function([tooltipItem], data): any {
                            const multistringText = ["Points: " + tooltipItem.xLabel];
                            multistringText.push("Grade: " + tooltipItem.yLabel);

                            return multistringText;
                        },
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data): any {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        top: 12
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    gridLines: {
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: false,
                                maxTicksLimit: 8,
                                stepSize: 5,
                                callback: function(value, index, values): any {

                                    if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
                                        return value;
                                    }
                                    if (value % 5 === 0) {
                                        return value;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: false,
                                min: 1,
                                max: 6
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Show full code or create fiddle.

Comment: The newly added tooltip setting should not be the problem, see this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/m5rq6bdj/3/ where the same option is used bit still the point circles are shown, the issue must be something else.

Comment: added full code for the chart,